# PUT метод в Retrofit2 + RxJava

Tags: android, retrofit, rxjava

Хочу спросить, как правильно работать с методом `PUT` в `Retrofit2`, я написала код, но неуверенна, что он правильный и хотела бы узнать, как правильно переписать этот код с помощью `RxJava`.

```
@PUT("{username}")
Call<Void> updateUser(@Path("username") String username,@Body User user);
```

И применение:

```
 private void updateUserInfo() {
        User user = new User("iryna", "Alala", "alala@gmail.com", "some properties" );
        Call<Void> deleteRequest = App.service.updateUser("bala", user);
        deleteRequest.enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) {
                // use response.code, response.headers, etc.
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {
                // handle failure
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

не забудьте про авторизацию

```
@PUT("{username}")
Observable<Response<Void>> updateUser(@Path("username") String username, @Body User user, @Header("Authorization") String auth);
```

и

```
private void updateUserInfo() {
   User user = new User("iryna", "Alala", "alala@gmail.com", "some properties" );
   yourService.updateUser("bala", user ...)
   .(...)
   .subscribe(response -> {
      // use response.code, response.headers, etc.
   }, throwable -> {
      // handle failure
   });
}
```

Comment: если конкретный ответ с сервера приходит, то замените Response<Void> на ваш response

Comment: А почему нужно использовать PATCH а не PUT? Как будет выглядеть реализация метода, когда будет Observable?

Comment: PATCH апдейтит только изменение поля. B User нада сетать только изменение поля, остальное null оставить.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24241893/rest-api-patch-or-put

Comment: Так а если в API прописано, что там должен быть метод PUT, а я буду использовать PATCH  - это не вызовет ошибку?

Comment: А как будет выглядеть реализация метода updateUserInfo() в случаи с RxJava?

Comment: если в api PUT, тогда используйте PUT.

Comment: я добавил updateUserInfo()